# user creation with command line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'd like to create to create an user account while customized command line installation and the following code does almost pretty well:

```
#!/bin/bash
#nameofuser stands for the new account
#skel is for the a skel folder outside /etc/skel     
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
read -p "Enter username : " nameofuser
read -s -p "Enter password : " password
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null

 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "$username exists!"
 exit 1

else
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
useradd -m -p $pass $nameofuser -c new created user -k $skel
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
fi
else
echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
exit 2
fi
```

I need some help with the second part and a reloop if the input is null or doesn't meet some password specs.

So this is about the second part

How could I make sure that the if statement proofs some stuff like minimum password lenth and if the password contains special chars and numbers or numbers at least?

How could I force the user to retype the password if this check does not meet the given values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
passwdok=0
while [ $passwdok == 0 ]  ; do
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    if [[ ! $password =~ ^.{6,} ]] ; then
        echo "Password should be at least 6 characters"
    elif [[ ! $password =~ [^A-Za-z0-9] ]] ; then
        echo "Password should contain a special character"
    else
        passwdok=1
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce strong passwords, don't do it in a script like this, but use the authentication system of Linux, called **PAM**, the *Pluggable Authentication Module*. In particular, enable the **cracklib** module. It involves something like editing `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` like this:

```
password required pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=6 difok=3
password required pam_unix.so md5 use_authtok
```

This is just an example, you probably want to customize this. Be careful when editing files under `/etc/pam.d`, if you make a mistake you can lock yourself out of your system.

[Here's a nice write-up on the subject](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html), and [here's the official documentation of PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html).

This way, you can effectively move the password strength validation out of your script. It should really be the responsibility of the authentication system anyway, and Linux makes this pretty easy for you.

If you have follow-up questions on this, try https://serverfault.com/.